# Phalcon : Exception: Wrong number of parameters

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I want to execute a prepared insert :

```
<?php
function add_record($tab) {

        $champs= "";
        $value = "";
        $separateur ="";
        $ins = array();

        foreach ($tab as $k => $v){
            $champs .= $separateur . $k;
            $value .= $separateur . "?" ;
            $ins[] = $v;
            $separateur = ",";
        }
        $champs = '('.$champs.')';
        $value = '('.$value.')';

        $sSQL = "INSERT INTO facture $champs VALUES $value";

        executePreparedDML($sSQL, $ins);

    }

    function executePreparedDML($sSQL, $tab) {
    $config = array(
        "host" => SERVEUR,
        "dbname" => BDD,
        "port" => BDD_PORT,
        "username" => LOGIN_DB,
        "password" => PWS_DB);
    $connection = new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql($config);
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sSQL);
    $pdoResult = $connection->executePrepared($statement, $tab);
}
?>
```

When executing the add_record function then I got this error : Exception: Wrong number of parameters ! So what is wrong ?

Comment: You are getting error for `executePreparedDML` or `executePrepared` ?

Comment: i get error for `$connection->executePrepared`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [manual](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/master/api/Phalcon_Db_Adapter_Pdo.html):

> public PDOStatement executePrepared (PDOStatement $statement, array $placeholders, array $dataTypes)
>
> Executes a prepared statement binding. This function uses integer indexes starting from zero

In [other part](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html#conditions) of manual we can see that Phalcon allows bindings of names eg. `= :email` or bindings indexed as of `?0, ?1`.

As you function is serving array of `[0 => 'first', 1 => 'second']`, i would test to create chain like `(?0, ?1, ?2, ?3, ?4)` instead of `(?,?,?,?,?)`.

You can also try to not prepare it the way you are doing it in question example and go straight for version from your own answer.

Also, when using models it is as easy as:

```
$obj = new credentialModel();
$isOk = $obj->save(array(
    'name' => 'John',
    'surname' => 'Doe'
));
```

and once you are using Phalcon, I would recommend to actually use it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the sql manually but not dynamically :

```
$tab["fact_date"] = convertDateFormat5($tab["fact_date"]);

        $config = array(
        "host" => SERVEUR,
        "dbname" => BDD,
        "port" => BDD_PORT,
        "username" => LOGIN_DB,
        "password" => PWS_DB);

        $connection = new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql($config);

        $sSQL = "insert into facture(user_code,clt_id,fact_ref,fact_lib,fact_date,fact_comm) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        $statement = $connection->execute($sSQL, array($tab['user_code'], $tab['clt_id'], $tab['fact_ref'], $tab["fact_lib"], $tab['fact_date'], $tab["fact_comm"]));
        $id = $connection->lastInsertId();
        $connection->close();

        return $id;
```

With this approach it works , so I dont understand why it doesnt when written dynamically !

Comment: I see a difference here. You are using here `$connection->execute($sSQL, $tabs)`, when in questions' example you are preparing (prepared) statepend and running `$connection->executePrepared($connection->prepare($sSQL), $tabs)`

Answer (score 0):

just go to `app/config/router.php` and replace this line of code `$router->handle()` with $`router->handle($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit round about way of doing things, but considering all else in code is good, ie the `$tab` values, etc. the error is see is...

`$sSQL = "INSERT INTO facture $champs VALUES $value";`
should be
`$sSQL = "INSERT INTO facture " .$champs. " VALUES ". $value;`

Comment: `echo`  the `$sql` and you should be able to see where the error is. Like I said, this way is a round about way of doing it. Write out the sql instead.

Comment: Downvote as in case of `"` php solves it properly. `"x $value x"` will produce same output as `"x " . $value . " x"`